# Função javascript está dando erro

Tags: javascript

Essa função nem está sendo chamada e está dando erro. Não diz exatamente o erro, mas dá erro logo ao entrar no formulário:

```
function ChangeSituacao(){
        var vRads = document.getElementsByName('ind_situacao');
        for(var i = 0; i < vRads.Length; i++){
            alert(vRads[i].checked);
    }
```

A idéia percorrer uma coleção de Radiobutton e pegar o que está checado e depois aplicar a regra do negócio. O que está errado essa função?

Comment: Você não ta fechando o seu for

Comment: `.Length` deve ser com letra pequena... => `.length`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu for não ta sendo fechado

```
function ChangeSituacao(){
        var vRads = document.getElementsByName('ind_situacao');
        for(var i = 0; i < vRads.Length; i++){
            alert(vRads[i].checked);
        } //Você esqueceu de fechar o for aqui
}
```